# On christmas lights plug which side do i connect the black wire to and which side do i connect the white wire and what do i do with the green wire

Tags: electrical

I am trying to connect a power cord to Christmas lights through the plug. Need to know which side do I connect the black wire into and which side do I connect the white wire and what do i do with the green wire on the power cord?

Comment: A picture of the original plug and the replacement would probably help. You can [edit] that into your question. However, "I am trying to connect a power cord to Christmas lights through the plug" is rather confusing. Are you trying to connect a second string of light to the existing one? Are you attempting to connect an extension cord to the lights? Are you trying to plug the lights into the cord? Maybe tell us what you're trying to achieve, instead of asking how to execute the solution you've come up with. We might be able to help you find an easier way to achieve your ultimate goal...